# What is the difference between verifying how strong is the relationship of variables on $\chi^2$ and correlation?

Tags: correlation, chi-squared-test, association-measure

While studying about probability distributions I found that distributions such as $\chi^2$ only would be able to tell if there **is** or there **is not** relation between a variable, but not how strong it is.

Later, it is pointed out that it is possible to observe how strong this relation holds using a method particular to this distribution. One of the methods suggested is **Yule's Q**.

I am well aware from my basic statistics course of correlation.

Is there a real difference between them?

Comment: There are several "$\chi^2$ tests", which one are you talking about ? I have in mind the $\chi^2$ test for $2\times 2$ table; this test assumes two independent binomial samples and the null hypothesis is the equality of the probabilities of success. Please precise your context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could find the formulas easily. **Yule's Q** is for binary data only and is
$$\frac{ad-bc}{ad+bc}$$
Yule's Q is a binary form of Goodman-Kruskal Gamma (and is thus related to Kendall's tau correlation). The binary form of **Pearson correlation** is called Phi:
$$\frac{ad-bc}{\sqrt{(a+b)(a+c)(b+d)(c+d)}}$$
You can see that these two are the same quantities, differently normalized by their respective denominators. The notation above:

- a - number of cases where characteristic is present in both variables
  X and Y.
- b - number of cases where characteristic present only in X.
- c - number of cases where characteristic present only in Y.
- d - number of cases where characteristic is absent in both variables.

Comment: thanks, I have weak background on statistics so I had a hard time understanding it from the book. I can understand from your explanation, but my question still remains: is there an difference on them? By difference I mean is one more expressive than the other or it only depends on the constraints? +1 for the very quick response and descriptions on them.

Comment: To be honest, I don't catch what you mean by "expressive" and "constraints". All difference between them comes from their formulas. Try to reflect on it or test some data, to see.

Comment: if they both tell you the correlation, are they expected to tell as answer the same result? is one more reliable than the other? does this makes more sense?