# Why does the Phi coefficient approximates the Pearson's correlation?

Tags: r, correlation

Going through the [Wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phi_coefficient) on the Phi coefficient, I've noticed that for paired binary data "a Pearson correlation coefficient estimated for two binary variables will return the phi coefficient".

Upon running a quick simulation I found this to not be the case.  However, it appears that the phi coefficient does approximate the pearson's correlation coefficient.

```
x <- c(1,   1,  0,  0,  1,  0,  1,  1,  1)
y <- c(1,   1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1)
cor(x,y)
sqrt(chisq.test(table(x,y))$statistic/length(x)) # phi

x <- rep(x, 1000)
y <- rep(y, 1000)
sqrt(chisq.test(table(x,y))$statistic/length(x)) # phi
# it now DOES approximates the pearsons correlation.
cor(x,y)
```

**But it is not apparent to me why (mathematically) this is the case.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, `chisq.test()` applies a continuity correction when computing the test statistic for 2x2 tables. If you switch off this behavior, then:

```
x = c(1,  1,  0,  0,  1,  0,  1,  1,  1)
y = c(1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1)
cor(x,y)
sqrt(chisq.test(table(x,y), correct=FALSE)$statistic/length(x)) # phi
```

will give you exactly the same answer. And this essentially also answers why $\sqrt{\chi^2/n}$ with the continuity correction approximates `cor(x,y)` -- as $n$ increases, the continuity correction has less and less influence on the result.

The continuity correction is described here: [Yates's correction for continuity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yates%27s_correction_for_continuity)

Comment: I am also interested as to why the two would give the exact same value.  Should I ask this on a different question?

Comment: @Tal, for **binary** data, that is, for 2x2 contingency table, _phi_ degenerates into abs(_r_). This can be shown by the fact that their classic formulas can be reduced to the common one shown [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26105/what-is-the-difference-between-verifying-how-strong-is-the-relationship-of-varia/26111#26111)

Comment: Does anyone have a textbook or journal reference for this?  I'd love to be able to give to my clients so they could cite it...