# Jaccard similarity coefficient vs. Point-wise mutual information coefficient

Tags: probability, distance-functions, mutual-information, association-measure, jaccard-similarity

Can you explain the **difference** between the **Jaccard similarity coefficient** and the **pointwise mutual information (PMI)** measure? It would be great if you could add a few examples.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These two are quite different. Still, let us try to "bring them to a common denominator", to see the difference. Both Jaccard and PMI could be extended to a continuous data case, but we'll observe the primeval binary data case.

Using a,b,c,d convention of the 4-fold table, as [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/256564/3277),

```
               Y
             1   0
            -------
        1  | a | b |
     X      -------
        0  | c | d |
            -------
a = number of cases on which both X and Y are 1
b = number of cases where X is 1 and Y is 0
c = number of cases where X is 0 and Y is 1
d = number of cases where X and Y are 0
a+b+c+d = n, the number of cases.
```

we know that $\text{Jaccard}[X,Y]= \frac {a}{a+b+c}$.

[PMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointwise_mutual_information) by Wikipedia definition is $\text{PMI}[X,Y]= \text{log}\frac {P(X,Y)}{P(X)P(Y)}$.

Let us first forget about "log" - because Jaccard implies no logarithming. Then plug a,b,c,d notation into PMI formula to obtain:

$$\frac {P(X = 1,Y = 1)}{P(X = 1)P(Y = 1)} = \frac{a/n}{\frac{a+b}{n}\frac{a+c}{n}} = \frac{an}{(a+b)(a+c)} = \frac{\frac{a}{\sqrt{(a+b)(a+c)}}}{\sqrt{\frac{a+b}{n}\frac{a+c}{n}}} = \frac{\text{Ochiai}[X,Y]}{\text{gm}[P(X),P(Y)]}$$

where "gm" is geometric mean of the two probabilities, and [Ochiai](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/61910/3277) similarity between X and Y vectors is just another name for cosine similarity in case of binary data: $\sqrt {\frac{a}{a+b}  \frac{a}{a+c}}$.

So, you can see that PMI (without logarithm) is Ochiai coefficient further "normalized" (or I'd say, de-normalized) by the overall probability of the two-way positive (eventful) data.

But Jaccard and Ochiai *are* comparable. Both are association measures ranging from 0 to 1. They differ in the accents they put on the potential discrepancy between frequencies $b$ and $c$. I've described it in the answer "Ochiai" above links to. To cite:

> Because product (seen in Ochiai) increases weaker than sum (seen in
>   Jaccard) when only one of the terms grows, Ochiai will be really high
>   only if both of the two proportions (probabilities) are high, which
>   implies that to be considered similar by Ochiai the two vectors must
>   share the great *shares* of their attributes/elements. In short,
>   Ochiai curbs similarity if **b** and **c** are unequal. Jaccard does
>   not.

Answer (score 4):

To supplement the top answer:

You want high Jaccard similarity, if you care about whether the two items co-occur frequently.
You want high PMI, if you care about how bigger than random the chances that the two items co-occur.

For two items with low probabilities and moderate co-occurrence, Jaccard will have really low scores, while PMI could give high scores.