# Accuracy of PMI (Pointwise Mutual Information) calculation from co-occurrence matrix

Tags: cooccurrence, pointwise-mutual-information

## Background

When calculate PMI or PPMI **from a co-occurrence matrix** (COM), it sums each row (co-occurrences) of the COM e.g. 2 for pineapple as in the formula in the snapshot. For this question, it is about words co-occurrences in a corpus text sequence.

[image]

## Question

Can the PMI formula calculate correct PMI **from a COM**? I think this part in the formula does not give the number of co-occurred words for the row `i`.

$\sum_{j=1}^Cf_{ij}$

### Example

Creating a COM from text sequence using N-Gram(N=5).

[image]

Each word between **or** and
**Q** has **four co-occurrence words (COW)**, e.g. (to, be, is, the) for the word **that**. However, the word **matters** at the end only has two COW (Q, that).

[image]

Therefore, $\sum_{j=1}^Cf_{ij}$ for each words are:

- 6 for **to** (i = 1)      --> cannot calculate from dividing by COW
- 7 for **be** (i = 2)      --> cannot calculate from dividing by COW
- 4 for **or** (i = 3)      --> `or occurred (4 / COW) times = 1`
- 4 for **not** (i = 4)     --> `not occurred (4 / COW) times = 1`
- 7 for **that** (i ==5)    --> cannot calculate from dividing by COW
- 4 for **is** (i = 6)      --> `is occurred (4 / COW) times = 1`
- 4 for **the** (i = 7)     --> `the occurred (4 / COW) times = 1`
- 4 for **Q** (i = 8)       --> `Q occurred (4 / COW) times = 1`
- 2 for **matter** (i = 9)  --> cannot calculate from dividing by COW

For those words at the ends of the corpus, $\sum_{j=1}^Cf_{ij}$ does not represents how many times the word at row `i` occurred.

### Workadound

By padding both ends of the corpus with NIL, the number of times when a word occured can be calculated via $\sum_{j=1}^Cf_{ij} / COW$ at each row `i`. However, a COM will not include such dummy NIL word counts.

Then the formula to calculate PMI/PPMI seems not to be completely accurate regarding those words at ends, although it could be negligible when the corpus size or vocabulary size is big.

Please help to clarify the accuracy of PMI, or if I misunderstand COM such as COM is different from my understanding and there is no such issue.

[image]

Comment: Will this instruct how to compute PMI? https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/256704/3277

Comment: @ttnphns, sorry but I am afraid it does not because my issue is specific to co-occurrence matrix and the words at the both ends of the corpus sequence. Probably my question was not clear enough. Update the question in an effort to be more clear.