# When to choose Hamann over Phi? Correlation insensitive to the shape of marginal distribution

Tags: distributions, correlation, binary-data, bounds

In his [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/256564/137088) to my [question on Hamann similarity](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/256556/whats-the-name-of-this-correlation-association-measure-between-binary-variables), user @ttnphns wrote

> If you want a "correlation" (or quasi-correlation) measure defying
>   marginal distributions shape - choose Hamann over Phi.

He illustrated there the effect of distributional asymmetry on both:

```
Crosstabulations:
        Y
X    7     1
     1     7
Phi = .75; Hamann = .75

        Y
X    4     1
     1    10
Phi = .71; Hamann = .75
```

I wonder **under which typical circumstances** I might want a "correlation defying marginal distributions shape" and choose Hamann, and under which circumstances I might want a "correlation *not* defying marginal distributions shape" and choose Phi?

Phi and Hamann are correlation measures for *binary* data. I'd like to hear, if possible, also about *continuous* data case: **what** might be a correlation coefficient for continuous data, similar to usual $r$ but not sensitive to the marginal distribution shape ($r$ can practically reach both its bounds -1 and +1 only in data with symmetric distribution).

Comment: I've added a question about continuous case as well, to make it more general and interesting. If you don't like the edit please feel free to roll back.